# How to have a jump to top link on a page that is split in half vertically no jscript or plugin

Tags: html, css

just wanted to know why the following code fails when the page is split in half. The goal is that when you click on the jump to top link it would go to the top of the page. But it does not. However if the body style css is removed then it does (well kind of)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#split {
  height: 100%;
}

#splitr {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <DIV id="jump"></DIV>

  <DIV id="split">
    <DIV id="splitr" class="right">
      <SPAN>
    <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p class="fivePad">Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
   <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>

<DIV> 
   <p><a href="#jump">Jump to top</a></p>
  </DIV>
   </SPAN>
    </DIV>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor that you are jumping to needs to be inside of the div that you have scrolled down.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#split {
  height: 100%;
}

#splitr {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="split">
    <div id="splitr" class="right">
        <a name="jump"></a>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p class="fivePad">Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Scelerisque diam adipiscing ad justo massa torquent vehicula dictumst netus consequat parturient at a parturient augue habitasse sem nulla a tempor vestibulum parturient.Mus fermentum a a tristique dignissim ullamcorper sit fringilla sociis eget rhoncus.</p>
        <p><a href="#jump">Jump to top</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need your div tag to be an `<a>` tag with the `name` attribute as such

`<a name="jump"></a>`

Comment: nvm the id would work also make sure to use lower cases

Comment: While on the right track, this alone will not solve it.